# ec2 user data script is only partialy excecuted

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am using ec2 instances with ubuntu 18 ami, 
with user data script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install python-pip -y
sudo apt-get install awscli -y
mkdir /home/ubuntu/dir
aws s3 sync s3://art-meta-data ./art-meta-data
```

the script it only partially executed, It installed pip, performs apt-get update, installed the awscli, but does not sync the bucket and does not create the directory.

I don't get any errors (maybe I don't look the right place?) and when I try to create the dir and sync the bucker via ssh, it works perfectly, meaning the s3 permissions and os permissions are fine.

What can be the issue here? What else should I check?

edit: 
I found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/) - explaining how to make your script run each time you stop and start the instance, but without explanation why the added meta coding changes anything. can anyone point me to some reference for why this script works differently than just regular bash script?

Comment: Where do you think `./art-meta-data` will go to?  I'm guessing it will be in the home directory of the `root` user or `/root`.  Did it get created there?

Comment: Scripts entered as user data are executed as the root user. Any files created will be owned by root.

Comment: "when I try to create the dir and sync the bucker via ssh, it works perfectly" - what do you mean by this? Are you running the script on the instance vs your local machine? Another important point to note is that if there is nothing to sync, you will not receive any output.

Comment: @thebeancounter, examine the cloud-init output log file at /var/log/cloud-init-output.log and look for error messages in the output.

Comment: I will check the sync and correct to a full path, I can't explain the mkdir issue, this is a full path, and not creating any dir. any idea what can possibly go wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to describe the full path on the sync command to avoid being created in the wrong place.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install python-pip -y
sudo apt-get install awscli -y
mkdir /home/ubuntu/dir
aws s3 sync s3://art-meta-data /home/ubuntu/dir/art-meta-data
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, also, this does not explain why the mkdir is not working (it uses full path)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the EC2 system logs to see the output of the failed command. That is really the only way for you to debug your an issue within your user data script.

Double check your instance profile has access to the bucket and that you are using the correct arn to reference the bucket

Comment: I have checked using ssh, the bucket permissions are fine, I can sync them manually without any problem. maybe the user data is running before the volume mount?

Comment: You didnt mention anything about mounting an EBS volume, but either way what do your EC2 system logs say?

Answer (score 2):

If you run `sudo cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log` you can see the log output of everything that happened while the ec2 user-data you supplied was run. Here's what you'd likely see if you did that:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/ubuntu/dir': No such file or directory
Jul 16 18:57:21 cloud-init[2471]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
Jul 16 18:57:21 cloud-init[2471]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Jul 16 18:57:21 cloud-init[2471]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
ci-info: no authorized ssh keys fingerprints found for user ec2-user.
Cloud-init v. 19.3-45.amzn2 finished at Sat, 16 Jul 2022 18:57:21 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 121.29 seconds
```

It appears that `mkdir` fails because `/home/ubuntu` doesn't yet exist at the time the ec2 user data script runs. One way to solve this would be to move the creation of the folder to `/etc/profile.d`.

To do this, you could modify your user data script as follows:

```
echo "mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/dir && aws s3 sync s3://art-meta-data /home/ubuntu/dir/art-meta-data" >> /etc/profile.d/sync_bucket.sh
```

Files in `/etc/profile.d/` are run when a user logs in so you're guaranteed the existence of `/home/ubuntu` folder and the sync will occur on each login.